# JAR/AAR dependency management between SDK and app built using SDK

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

For the SDK that we develop, we are looking at the right approach to address dependency conflicts when both the SDK project and the client app (that is built using the SDK) use the same 3rd-party libraries (say, Otto from Square, Android Annotations etc), may not necessarily be the same exact version of the 3rd-party library.

I noticed that gradle provides a setting like so:

`dependencies {
    compile("org.gradle.test.excludes:api:1.0") {
        exclude module: 'shared'
    }
}`

While this approach is clean, I see a disadvantage in that, the SDK developer needs to inform the SDK users all the libraries they are using in their project and hence the libraries' are no kept "hidden".

The other alternative is to use a tool like [jarjar](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jarjar/) to repackage the JAR libraries. While I never used this tool, it does appear simple, but having to do this every time a new version of the library is available, may not be a good approach either.

Any pointers would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the SDK developer needs to inform the SDK users all the libraries they are using in their project and hence the libraries' are no kept "hidden"

Not really. The developer integrating your SDK can [use Gradle to determine what the transitive dependencies are](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_dependencies) and make adjustments.

> The other alternative is to use a tool like jarjar to repackage the JAR libraries. While I never used this tool, it does appear simple, but having to do this every time a new version of the library is available, may not be a good approach either.

AFAIK, jarjar only works for JARs. Not all Android dependencies are JARs, as you note in your question title. For AARs, AFAIK, you would have to create your own `aaraar` tool that could handle changing all resources, assets, and so forth to new names, so they do not conflict with the original AAR. This may prove difficult.

Comment: Thank you. True that the developers integrating with my SDK are responsible for specifying the exclusions but, when I update the sample app to demonstrate integrating SDK, I myself have to do that as well. Also, yes, for AARs, we would need to find an ```aaraar``` tool.